# integrable, measure-theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hi I need to know how I can see if f is integrable and how I can write 
$\int_\Omega$ f d$\mu$ maybe you can help me. It is enough if I estimate f
by a function whose integral I can calculate. Thanks a lot.

1.$ (Ω,*A*,μ)$ = (N,*P*(N),μ)  μ is  counting measure, n $\in$ N, f(n)=1/n

2.$ (Ω,*A*,μ)$ = (N,*P*(N),μ)  μ is counting measure, n $\in$ N              , $f(n) = (−1)^n *\frac{1}{n}$

3.$ (Ω,*A*,μ)$ = (N,*P*(N),μ) $μ(A)$=$\sum_{n \in A}$ $\frac{1}{n}$  A⊆N, $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: and I forgot f: Ω→\overlineR

Comment: Counting measure turns the integral into a sum.

Comment: You don't need to keep writing the same thing over and over. Just say the measurable space is $(\mathbb N$, $P(\mathbb N))$ once at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since we know that counting measure converts an integral into a sum. Therefore,
   $\int_\mathbb{N} f(n) d\mu(n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)\mu(\{n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)$ which we know is divergent. So, f is not integrable.
2. Same procedure as part-1. Here, f is not integrable since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mid(-1)^n*(1/n)\mid = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)$ is divergent.
3. Consider,
   $\int_\mathbb{N}f(n)d\mu(n)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\mu(\{n\})= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)*(1/n)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)^2$ which is convergent. So, f is integrable.

Comment: No, the $f$ in 2. is not integrable, since $\int |f| d\mu = \infty.$